# Fishy Issue with GET in pm2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose, pm2

I wrote a simple get function. I have a pm2 server in AWS. I have tested the code in my local node server. It was perfectly working fine. Then I upload the code to AWS. The GET function is working on that day which I upload. Next day it was not working. I fixed with some solution again it was working on that day and next day it as not working(**returning empty array**)

**Code**

```
getDetail = (req, res) => {
this._model.find({ code: req.body.code }, (err, obj) => {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    } else {
        res.send(obj);
    }
});
```

}

**Request**

```
{"code":"CT-123-345-234-233-423344"}
```

**Model**

```
  {
   "_id":"5d3189a00789e24a23438a0d",
   "status":"active",
   "code":"CT-123-345-234-233-423344",
   "created_Date":"2019-07-19T09:13:04.297Z",
   "updated_Date":"2019-07-19T09:13:04.297Z",
   "__v":0
  }
```

Comment: If you could share the code or a git link. @Chris

Comment: That's a private repo @PrasantaBose. I have shared the code above please take a look

Comment: I'm assuming you are using mongoose. Or, it's MongoClient? @Chris

Comment: mongoose @PrasantaBose